# Virto Commerce - Themes compatibility with Shopify Themes

Tags: virtocommerce

The Doco for Virto Commerce sais that it is compatible, but whether I import a theme from Shopify using the import tool or upload a Shopify theme directly to a store, I get the following error.

```
FileNotFoundException: The template 'content_header' was not found. The following locations were searched:<br/>Themes\Electronics\Debut\templates<br/>Themes\Electronics\Debut\snippets<br/>Themes\Electronics\Debut\layout<br/>Themes\Electronics\Debut\assets
```

Are the Shopify themes usable in Virto Commerce or does it need development?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Virto Commerce Storefront Theming is only `partially` compatible with Shopify Liquid Themes and has some limitations and required development effort for theme adaptation, even more, **this process may not be straightforward for some cases** and requires a good knowledge for Virto storefront application and the key principles of theme development.

Unfortunately, we don't have a manual on how to convert the Shopify theme to Virto but I can provide you some list of compatibility and similarities that might you help:

- Virto has the same theme structure with Shopify.

  - [Shopify theme structure](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-templates)
  - Virto theme structure

[image: Virto theme structure]

- Virto uses the `Liquid` as the primary syntax  for  end-user templates
- Virto uses mostly the same with `Shopify Liquid` object and variables [Shopify Cheat Sheet](https://cheat.markdunkley.com/) but with some limitations and incompatibilities. Here it is [not completed list of incompatibles of Virto Liquid objects with Shopify](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront-core/wiki/How-to:-Migrate-theme-to-new-4.%D1%85-storefront-version-powered-by-Scriban-template-engine)
- Virto uses modern JS web frameworks such (Angular, VueJS, AngularJS) in its own themes to implement missed in the `Shopify` themes functionality is required for shopping experiences such as Checkout, Account management, etc.

Here are some links to the sample Virto themes that can be used as a starting point for your custom theme development:

- [ODT-MPA starter theme](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-odt-mpa-theme) - VueJs MPA theme. It might be considered as a good starting point but it still under development.
- [Procurement portal theme](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-procurement-portal-theme) - Angular Hybrid theme is used the advantages of both SPA and SSR approaches. It has very basic functionality implemented.
- [Virto default theme](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-default) - AngularJS theme. Most full-featured theme but it uses outdated JS framework AngularJS 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem, related to this code
https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront-core/blob/ff774a1e318d702a5203ae5aaa6ef1a5c7a499da/VirtoCommerce.LiquidThemeEngine/LiquidThemedView.cs#L88

I think should be content_for_header.

As a workaround, I can offer to create empty content_header.liquid snippet.